# Where is the code of downloaded Chrome Packaged Apps?

Tags: google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

As a CPA developer I spend my days actualizing my unpacked app in the Extensions page with. And when I launch my app I can see from this page the view `myApp.html` and inspect it (or directly from the app like a webpage).

But when I download an app from the Chrome Web Store this is different: the only view available is `background.js` and I have not find a way to inspect the other views.

So this is the question: if you downloaded an app from the Chrome Web Store, is there a way to see all the code of the app?

This question is very important to me, the worst part of shipping a CPA is to minified it to be sure it cannot be easily read by malicious users and now I am not sure if there is a way to analyze apps downloaded from the Chrome Web Store.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you try using Chrome Apps Developer Tools? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-developer-too/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc?hl=en

Comment: Is the root of the question that your are shipping code you do not want anyone to see?  You should know that the packaged app install file is just a zip of all your assets which anyone can download.  Don't ship code you don't want anyone to read, I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As Dinh Viêt Hoà said in comments, HTML pages (and all the JS code linked with these pages) can be analyzed using the app [Chrome Apps Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-developer-too/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc?hl=en).

Comment: The source of any Chrome app/extension can also be viewed using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin (full disclosure: I developed this viewer)